# SignalR WPF Client can't reach hub deployed on IIS when IIS runs on a different system

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I just play a little bit with signalR. My application has only one simple hub which is stored in an ASP.NET Application and I wrote a **WPF client**, which interacts via the hubconnection and the created proxy with the ASP.NET Application. Everything works fine on my local PC. I deployed the **ASP.NET Application** on **IIS**.

Now I am getting to the point...

When I type the following into my browser on **my own** PC (pcthi-and)

```
http://pcthi-and:8080/signalr/hubs
```

I'll get what I want

When I type the same url into a browser of **another** pc I'll get **the same response and everything looks fine.**

But my Application only works on my pc and not on the other one. When I start the hubconnection on the other pc I don't get a connectionId.

I tried to change the url to my IP-Address without effect.

Browser call to hub works but the Application doesn't work.

**The call** looks like this:

```
private bool tryToConnectToCoffeService()
    {
        try
        {
            this.hubConnection = new HubConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["coffeeConnection"].ConnectionString);

            this.hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            this.coffeeService = this.hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("coffee");

            this.hubConnection.Start();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubConnection.ConnectionId))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**The Global.asax:**

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

The hub like this

```
[HubName("coffee")]
public class CoffeeHub : Hub
{
```

My Hub Connection String is this:

```
"http://pcthi-and:8080/"
```

Or:

```
"http://My-Current-IP-Address:8080/"
```

I use SignalR 1.0 rc2.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks for helping.

Cheers

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
hubConnection.Start();
```

to

```
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

If you are running .NET 4.5 you could make the `tryToConnectToCoffeService` method `async` and then `await` when you start the hub connection.

```
await hubConnection.Start();
```

It likely works today on localhost because the client can finish connecting before `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubConnection.ConnectionId))` executes.

It is probably taking longer to connect from another machine which exposes the race condition present when you don't wait for `HubConnection.Start()` to complete.

Comment: thank you very much, yesterday I read your post and I was really looking forward to follow your advice at work, and it works ;-)! thanks a lot.