# Alternative to polling on REST service?

Tags: ajax, wcf, rest, mobile

I have to implement a REST WebService that has different Clients (Silverlight, WPF). The point is to make use of the http advantages. I must push updates tp my clients (and i have no idea, what is the best option for that). Most of the tutorials are about using REST and Comet for chating application, which is not suitable for my case. I cant find any samples for my senario

1) Is polling a good practice? Will i eventually face some problems? Which one?

2) I want to introduce a web client (silverlight and also WPF) soon, but i dont know how we can poll in AJAX(never used AJAX) and i am wondering if it is possible to do it.

3) I wanted the service to be REST because of interoperability. I want it to work with WPF, Silverlight, JAVA, Javascript(AJAX) and mobile devices. So if i want to introduce push notification(if it is even possible with REST), how will it work with WPF/Silverlight, AJAX.

If you have code examples, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Not good. But when dealing with HTTP without WebSockets you have no choice either polling or long polling. If it's possbile to use WebSockets and/or SingnalR, then you're avoiding of polling and improve performance.

2) jQuery.ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

3) Look at SignalR and SingnalR samples

http://signalr.net/

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

http://www.asp.net/signalr

And one more hint. From my experience it's almost always possible to redesign clients or UI interface to avoid polling at all. Be sure that there is no other way except polling. And when you aren't working with legacy application then WebSockets using SignalR is your way

**UPD**:
When speaking not about legacy application or maintenance, then definitely for REST services in Microsoft stack answer will be ASP.NET Web API for REST service with or without SignalR. SignalR is library that will help you with your push notifications even if clients aren't supporting WebSockets. It works adaptively, and if client is not supporting WebSockets it will try to use other techniques including polling and long polling.

Nuget package inlcudes also silverlight lib

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/

Take a look at SignalR console sample. It will be not a problem to use SignalR libraries from any .NET client
https://github.com/SignalR/Samples/tree/master/BasicChatConsole

Samples and tutorials on how to make REST services with ASP.NET Web API are here

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: thank you for your reply i have edit my question. may be you can help me.

Comment: thank you again for your reply. I will read more about signalR but, i am not sure if it is supporting Clients like WPF-Application.

Could you post an example, which contains a client that is not supporting WebSockets?

Comment: It is supporting clients like Silverlight and WPF. I've wrote about it. And there are samples. SignalR is technology supported by Microsoft. Without it you can always implement polling manually, by why to waste time - is up to you.

Comment: I found this post i think it is gonna work :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836065/signalr-wpf-client-cant-reach-hub-deployed-on-iis-when-iis-runs-on-a-different

thank you very much