# Real-Time communication with REST server

Tags: rest, real-time

I'm looking for the common solution to deal with the real-time client for server with REST API. Is it any particular way to do it except of regular, sequential server polling/quering?
Any interesting articuel about it?

Comment: Polling is common but if you can avoid it great. Two other options are WebSockets and signalIR. WebSockets is great if it's available to you. See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054074/alternative-to-polling-on-rest-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been reading about long-pooling and python tornado serever. It fits the best to my needs.
http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

There are web sockets, which are broadly supported by modern web browsers and servers.

Libraries exist in for various frameworks, for example

Nodejs: http://socket.io/

ASP.NET world: http://signalr.net/

PHP: http://socketo.me/

These have web socket support and even a fallback using polling when web socket are not supported in browser/server.

Comment: Thx, but it must be pure REST. No web sockets. When IP change (what happend quite offen in case of mobiles) Web socket communication will hang. I already have this REST API and Im thinki how to make a real time client

Comment: In signalR, you can turn off the use of web sockets entirely, for example: 
connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
I believe there are similar options for the other libraries